# Changing the installation directory of a package with package-manager Apper or Software Center?

Tags: debian, security, package-management

Is it possible to change the installation directory of a specific package and its dependencies with a package-manager such as Apper or Software Center?

Besides modifying the .deb file after hash-verification or creating symlinks it would also need to set the appropriate permissions (or prompt the user with a GUI to configure them) and take the differing package-location into account when updating packages including showing a dialog when other packages have dependencies that do not reside in the default location.

Installing to separate locations seems to be needed due to the lack of sandboxing features.

How are people usually doing this if not via package-managers?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is really supported by package manager - they locate everything at `/` and the package can place files anywhere on your filesystem from there - there is no real enforcement beyond what the package maintainers will accept (normally by sticking to the standards for where files should be placed).

You have a couple options - compile the package yourself, you can then normally chooses the location to install to typically be specifying `PREFIX` or `DESTDIR` but that depends entirely on what you are trying to install and how it is built.

Another option is to use chroots with a minimal system that you can place anywhere you like. This disadvantage is that this is basically a separate system within your main system that has to be managed separately (ie you have to have apt/yum or what ever installed inside the chroot and update the application from inside the chroot.

Now, depending on what you are actually trying to do you have some other options.

1. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) - if your application is a cli based you can run it in an isolated environment using docker - then you can have as many different versions of the application running at once all isolated from each other.
2. A bundling system like [flatpak](http://flatpak.org/) or [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) which work by packages application up into bundles with all their dependencies allowing you to install multiple version of things along side each other (kind of like how OS X handles applications).

Both of these are basically sandboxing solutions that sound more like what you are after.